# CSS div width - content width only..?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm trying to get my div to be the width of my content, I can get it working in all the other browsers except for IE, using:

```
div#quoteHolder {
  height: 85px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this in IE?

Oh and this is the html code..

```
<div id="quoteContainer">
  <div id="quoteHolder">
    <h2>"If you were lucky and lived in Port Melbourne, it might even be your local"</h2>
    <h3>The Age, Epicure. JUNE 22nd 2004</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Another solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304037/css-div-width-content-width-only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE supports inline-block, but only for elements that are natively inline. So, if you really want to use inline-block, you’re restricted to spans and strongs and ems, when a list or paragraph would perhaps make more semantic sense (and also degrade more nicely for non-CSS users.)

However, if you trigger hasLayout(set hasLayout=true in that element) on a block element, and then set it to display:inline, it magically becomes an inline-block in IE! By using the property hack (which I love so well), you can hide the display:inline from all non-IE browsers effortlessly.

Here’s the code, in all its brief loveliness:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

Comment: Magic! I spent so much time looking for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IE has problems with a lot of `display` modes, see here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html. A `float: left` might be what you're looking for, alternatively `display: inline`, but then the `height` won't work.

Comment: display inline will remove the height of 85 px

Comment: Thanks for that, the height 85px is not necessary, it was only there for me to see my div (with a border), I've used display: inline and it works perfectly, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
div#quoteHolder {
  height: 85px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
```